# Передать constraint из View в Controller (MVC)

Tags: swift, mvc, uikit, constraints

Пишу свой первый проект на архитектуре MVC.
Я новичок и могу упустить простое. Но никак не могу разобраться как реализовать constraint во View и предать в Controller.

**Вот мой View:**

```
    
    class ViewExample: UIView {
        
        var textView: UITextView = {
            let textView = UITextView()
            textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            textView.text = "Hello, world!"
            
            return textView
        }()
        
        func setupViews() {
            addSubview(textView)
            
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                textView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 10),
                textView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
                textView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -10),
                textView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 2)
            ])
        }
        
        override init(frame: CGRect){
            super.init(frame: frame)
            setupViews()
        }
        
        required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
            super.init(coder: coder)
            setupViews()
        }
    }
```

**Вот мой Controller:**

```
        class ViewController: UIViewController {
            
            override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()
                
                let ve = ViewExample()
                ve.setupViews()
                view.addSubview(ve)
            }
        
        }
```

Что мне нужно исправить, чтоб это работало?

Comment: Что именно передать и как должно работать? Вы хотите использовать `ViewExample` в качестве view для контроллера?

Comment: У меня не передаются ограничение(constraint). В ViewController они работают, но когда и сами элементы там. Вот в этом и проблема. 
И ведь не один элемент textView будет находится во View.
Уже третий день не могу разобраться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если Вы хотите программно создавать UI, создавайте отдельный UIView и используйте его вместо view контроллера. По примеру в вопросе:

```
import UIKit

class ViewExample: UIView {
    // Добавляете все необходимые элементы и располагаете как хотите
    ...
}


class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let contentView = ViewExample()
    
    override func loadView() {
        view = contentView
    }
}
```

Следующая итерация улучшения – композиция, передаёте view в инициализатор, пример:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private let contentView: ViewExample
    
    init(contentView: ViewExample) {
        self.contentView = contentView
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func loadView() {
        view = contentView
    }
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Похоже я еще явно не умею формулировать мысль. Но благодаря Вашим ответам - я пришел к решению.
Это оказалось слишком просто..

**View:**

```
class ViewEx: UIView {
    
    lazy var textView: UITextView = {
        let textView = UITextView()
        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textView.text = "Hello, world!"
        textView.textAlignment = .center
        textView.backgroundColor = .gray
        
        return textView
    }()
    
}
```

**Controller:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
        
         let ve = ViewEx()
        
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            
            addSubviews()
            setupConstraint()
        }
        
        func addSubviews() {
            view.addSubview(ve.textView)
        }
    
        func setupConstraint() {
            
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                ve.textView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 10),
                ve.textView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
                ve.textView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -10),
                ve.textView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: ve.textView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 2)
            ])
        }
        
}
```